# how to resolve this "mysqli extension is missing" error after update php7 to 8 in windows apache24?

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

[image]

I am using apache24 on windows.
phpmyadmin working well on PHP version 7.4.26, after I changed PHP version 8.1.4 following error occurred (screenshot). I am also tried with PHP version 8.0.17 but the same error

I am enabled required extensions also such as "mysqli, mbstring, pdo_mysql" but not working with same error

this is my apche24 httpd.conf

```
PHPIniDir “C:/php8”
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php_module 'C:/php8/php8apache2_4.dll'
```

Answer (score 0):

This message says your php engine don't have the mysqli extension enabled...

So, you can try, on your php.ini:

```
extension=mysqli # (or the path to the extension module, like: C:/php8/ext/php_mysqli.dll, assuming the path on your post....
```

Remember to restart apache if you're running php as an module, or the php wrapper, if is an cgi-like)

And make sure your environment configuration is pointing to the correct php.ini for the environment you are running as you have more than one version installed...path precedence can be an issue.

Comment: I have tried this also but not working. I am checked with php -m command , it's showing mysqli entension is enable

Comment: I am facing the same situation as you were, please tell me how did you resolve this issue @M.Pratheep